# Swift - Passing variable from one cell to another?

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have 2 cells, both loaded from xib files. cell1 has a label, and cell2 has a label. In cellForRowAt I declare a variable when I load cell2 and want that variable to be passed to cell1.

**My attempted solution**

I have tried to store the local var '**importantVar**' inside a global var called '**importantVarCapture**' and then pass cell1.cell1Label.text the global var, but however, as cell1 has already loaded, this fails.

So in short, I want to somehow update cell1 after my cell2 has finished loading and the 'importantVar' has been declared.

I've created a fresh xCode project to replicate my problem and the code is below:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    var importantVarCapture: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell1")
        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "Cell2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell2")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell1") as? Cell1
            cell1?.cell1Label.text = self.importantVarCapture
            return cell1!
        } else {
            let importantVar = "Hello World"
            self.importantVarCapture = importantVar
            let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell2") as? Cell2
            cell2?.cell2Label.text = importantVar
            return cell2!
        }
    }
}
```

Below are my xib files:

```
class Cell1: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell1Label: UILabel!

}


class Cell2: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cell2Label: UILabel!

}
```

P.S - I have recently tried to ask this question, and tried to delete the question but have been unable. My previous question didn't have the code and was too messy. I have created this fresh XCode project to replicate my problem. Please do accept my apologies for the duplicate, and I appreciate any help.

Comment: Basically, when I load the cell (cell2) I pull some details from a model which is populated in a URLSession. I appreciate loads of things aren't best practices here, I'm just wondering the best way to get the data i pull in cell2 to cell1.

Comment: In my real project, cell1 is a total price, and cell2 and others have individual prices

Comment: Above is real code, the concept of the above is what I need to achieve in my actual project ?

Comment: I have replicated the problem above without the need of the URLSession and the rest of my application. I'd rather delete my first question if possible and have an answer to my much simpler example above. If I received help to the above, I'd be able to apply it to my bigger project.